# Can Perl's Text::CSV_XS be used to remove columns from CSVs?

Tags: perl, csv

For work purposes, I have several CSV files which have been modified by a vendor upgrade, and they now contain approximately 80 more columns than they used to. The downside is, these files are used for billing, so we need to trim off the new columns. The upside is all of the columns have been added to the end of the record. The older records contained 251 columns. The new records contain 336.

So, the script I am writing will accept the CSV filename as an argument, edit it in place because the files can be very large, remove the first two lines and the last line, and finally remove the new columns (not just empty their contents, completely remove them, so if the original format had N columns, the new format after being processed should only have N columns)

Here is what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#Use Tie::File to modify file contents directly on disk, without reading
#to memory.
use Tie::File;

#Use Text::CSV_XS to quickly remove columns from CSV. External library
#used to compensate for quoted fields.
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csvparser = Text::CSV_XS->new () or die "".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag();
my $file;

foreach $file (@ARGV){
        my @CSVFILE;
        my $csvparser = Text::CSV_XS->new () or die "".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag();
        tie @CSVFILE, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;
        shift @CSVFILE;
        shift @CSVFILE;
        pop @CSVFILE;
        for my $line (@CSVFILE) {
                $csvparser->parse($line);
                my @fields = $csvparser->fields;
                splice @fields, -85;
                $line = $csvparser->combine(@fields);
        }

        untie @CSVFILE;
}
```

This will run, and the first portion runs correctly (removing the first 2 and last lines). However I am unsure how to proceed with removing the new columns. I have been reading through the docs for Text::CSV_XS and I can't seem to find any functions which would remove a column. Some of the examples may be helpful, but I confess my perl skills aren't very good. My main reason for wanting to use the module is that these CSV files do occasionally contain fields with commas, enclosed in quotes, which the module can handle.

Any suggestions about how to approach this would be wonderful. Also if there is an issue with my approach, please let me know. I'm by no means a perl expert and am open to any helpful criticism since this will be getting fed into a billing system.

**EDIT:** Included suggestions from below into code. As mentioned below, when running this the source file's contents get replaced with a single "1" on every line.

Comment: *Please* don't use capitals for Perl local variables. They are reserved for global names like `@ARGV` and `Text::CSV_XS`.

Comment: I was under the impression based on the old camel book that the standard was to use all caps for filehandles? http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/perlnut/ch04_09.htm
Has that style changed??

Comment: Old-style filehandles were *global* as well, and so all-caps. Current best practice is to use a lexical scalar variable for file handles, so it's now `open my $fh, '<', 'filename'` instead of `open FH, 'filename'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you ask, although I wouldn't hope for any great speed.

Something like this should work

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new or die Text::CSV_XS->error_diag;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {

    tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;

    splice @lines, 0, 2;
    pop @lines;

    for my $line (@lines) {
        $csv->parse($line);
        my @fields = $csv->fields;
        splice @fields, -80;
        $csv->combine(@fields);
        $line = $csv->string;
    }

    untie @lines;
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track, however after doing this the file is full of "1"s. I've updated the question with the new code. I appreciate your help thus far!

Comment: @Matthew: Sorry, there seems to have been a casualty between my IDE and this post. There was a line of code missing. Should work fine now.

Comment: Rather than removing the trailing 80 columns I would much rather this code *kept* a specific number of columns. However you don't ay how many there should be left after removing the unwanted 80. Presumably you do know, so you can replace the `-80` with that number.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to only have 251 columns, as mentioned the vendor upgrade added 85 columns, making the new total 336. Our billing system is set up to handle that number of fields, and is having trouble with the new ones that have been added.

Comment: Ah OK, then you want `splice @fields, 251`